# Does 100% pure honey expire?

Tags: honey

The bottle has a best by date. The bottle has been stored in a cool dry place away from sunlight. Does anyone have a clue?

I know they discovered honey thousands of years old but that is probably a very specific type.

Comment: Are you asking whether there’s a change or degradation in the quality of the honey, or whether it’s still safe to consume?

Comment: @Sneftel.Thank you that would certainly explain the best buy date on the bottle. Me bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, honey last "forerver".

It might crystalize overtime , but you can liquify it with a little bit of heat.

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/the-science-behind-honeys-eternal-shelf-life-1218690/

As always, if you do not feel safe eating something, just throw it.

Comment: Outstanding article.